# 90s Sci-Fi series about a vigilante with a bullet proof suit

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to find an old series that I saw on TV in the 90s.

I don't remember exactly the plot just fragments but it was about a vigilante of some sort. I remember he had a cool black costume that had some sort of force field around it that made it bullet proof. I remember a motorcycle too (not sure though) which also had the same force field.

It was a short TV series or maybe it was a pilot for something that didn't make it into a series.

Comment: Was the lead character disabled? I vaguely recall seeing on TV a guy who was shot and paralyzed, and then his research assistant fails to follow protocol and finds some combination that allows the protagonist to walk and also be bullet proof. He goes on to seek justice.

Comment: You say short TV series and movie and both quite confidently. Do you know which it actually was?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: TV series. There was a short episode each weekend in my country

Comment: @KevinO: No, I don't think he was paralyzed... but I also remember a series like you mention too... now I'm wondering about that series also :D

Comment: My first thought was *M.A.N.T.I.S.*, but that was from the 90s, plus you already have an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Super Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Force) (1990)

> The series is about a former astronaut who uses an advanced combat
>   suit and motorcycle to fight crime in the city of Metroplex during the
>   year 2020. Among the features of the suit were enhanced strength and
>   armament, whereas the motorcycle had an array of James Bond-type
>   gadgets and weapons.

Comment: Yes, this is it :) The costume isn't as cool as I remembered it but this is indeed the series.. Thank you!

Comment: There were a variety of these in the 1980s. Street Hawk was my fave; https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088618/